# Inherited database has leap year code that compiler doesn't like

Tags: ms-access, vba

In my job, I have inherited an Access 97 database. This database is very unstable and I need to remedy that in one way or another. I have been trying to go through and debug the current version so that I can migrate it to 2007. I have run across some code that the compiler doesn't like and not sure how to fix it...here is the code:

```
    Function DaysInMonth(ByVal D As Date) As Long
    ' Requires a date argument because February can change
    ' if it's a leap year.
    Select Case Month(D)
      Case 2
        If LeapYear(Year(D)) Then
         DaysInMonth = 29
        Else
         DaysInMonth = 28
        End If
      Case 4, 6, 9, 11
        DaysInMonth = 30
      Case 1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12
        DaysInMonth = 31
   End Select
   End Function
```

I get a compile error: Sub or Function not defined and it highlights the first "LeapYear".

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

`LeapYear` is another function or procedure that appears not be present in your modules or has been made Private. `LeapYear` isn't a VBA function. There must have been a function that takes a year `Year(D)` and returns `TRUE` or `FALSE` if it's a leapyear. either insert one or set the existing one to Public

Edit:You could use [IsLeapYear](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DateTimeVBA.htm) but change to 'LeapYear' and call using IsLeapYear(D)

Answer (score 2):

The code in question is idiotic -- it was clearly written by somebody who didn't have a clue about VBA dates, which already know everything that is needed without needed to encode this crap into a CASE SELECT.

This expression will get you the number of days in a month:

```
  Day(DateAdd("m", 1, DateValue(Month(Date()) & "/1/" & Year(Date()))) - 1)
```

What this does is get the first of the current month, adds a month to it (for the first of the next month), and then subtracts 1 from it. Since the integer part of the VBA date type is the day part, that will get you the last day of the current month. Then you take the result and pull the day out with the Day() function.

Coding that up as a function:

```
  Function DaysInMonth(ByVal dteDate As Date) As Integer
    Dim dteFirstOfMonth As Date
    Dim dteLastOfMonth As Date

    dteFirstOfMonth = DateValue(Month(dteDate) & "/1/" & Year(dteDate))
    dteLastOfMonth = DateAdd("m", 1, dteFirstOfMonth) - 1
    DaysInMonth = Day(dteLastOfMonth)
  End Function
```

You could also code this up using the fact that the DateSerial() function treats the zeroth day as the last of the previous month:

```
  Function DaysInMonth(ByVal dteDate As Date) As Integer
    Dim dteOneMonthFromDate As Date
    Dim dteLastOfThisMonth As Date

    dteOneMonthFromDate = DateAdd("m", 1, dteDate)
    dteLastOfThisMonth = DateSerial(Year(dteOneMonthFromDate), Month(dteOneMonthFromDate), 0)
    DaysInMonth = Day(dteLastOfThisMonth)
  End Function
```

But that doesn't make it any shorter...

None of this requires figuring out leap year rules -- those are built into the VBA date type.

And, of course, the function should not return a Long, but an Integer, since the maximum value it can ever return is 31.

Comment: If selecting the return type by the range of possible return values, why not return Byte?

Comment: No real reason, I guess, other than I like to use the VBA data types that are most closely related to the Jet/ACE data types that I use commonly. Because of legacy issues, I've never much used BYTE in my Jet/ACE data tables, so barely ever use it in VBA, as well.

Answer (score 1):

LeapYear may not be your only issue.

In Access '97, go to the VBA editor and click "Tools/References":
[image: References 1]

Look in the references of your '97 project and see what DLLs are listed.

A screen will appear that shows you the ActiveX DLLs that can be used for the project.  The ones that are checked are the ones currently used:
[image: References 2]

Odds are there is a DLL there that needs to be referenced in your new 2007 database.